# How do I sync my Android application with Couchbase Server?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, ektorp, touchdb

I am struggling to differentiate between all of the different couch* technologies that are out there. I've been flip-flopping between using CouchDB and using Couchbase Server for an Android game that I'm developing and the lack of documentation is frustrating.

**My understanding of the technologies:**

- *CouchDB* - A no-SQL database that has been under development for the last few years and is communicated with using a RESTful API. It has
  been abandoned by its chief developers in favor of working on
  Couchbase Server.
- *Couchbase Server* - An enterprise solution to a large database where low-latency is paramount. It keeps 'hot' data in memory using
  memcached but data is persisted to a CouchDB database.
- *Couchbase Mobile* - A mobile implementation of CouchDB  **<--Legacy**
- *TouchDB* - A mobile implementation of CouchDB.
- *Ektorp* - A framework that allows a developer to talk to and sync with a CouchDB instance from Java.

What's missing in my list is a framework to talk to **Couchbase Server** from **Android** (and eventually iOS).

Does such a framework exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sync an application to Couchbase Server, typically an application built atop TouchDB, the framework you're seeking is Mobile Syncpoint as [listed on the Couchbase wiki](http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Mobile+Syncpoint).  It's an Open Source work in progress, but coordinates for dev mailing lists, and concepts link off of that wiki.

Typically you'd use Ektorp atop TouchDB, then use Mobile Syncpoint to sync to Couchbase Server running in a datacenter somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you **don't** want *Couchbase Server* on Android, but rather you want to have your Android app talk to a *Couchbase Server* instance on a remote server somewhere.

The primary interface for *Couchbase Server* **is** memcached, and so any memcached library for Android will work.  If needed, any of the remaining Couch calls are simple HTTP calls.